# MultiBinding with binding StringFormat

Tags: wpf, binding, multibinding

I am trying to display some label with MultiBinding with Binding on StringFormat.

Like that:

```
<Label.Content>
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{Binding LabelStringFormat, Source={DynamicResource Texts}}">
                <Binding Path="Lib1" />
                <Binding Path="Lib2" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
</Label.Content>
```

LabelStringFormat can be something like "[{0}/{1}]" or something like that. It is known in build but must be used from Resource.

But when I use something like code above, I get error:

```
A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'StringFormat' property of type 'MultiBinding'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.
```

I can use binding on Content and create string in ViewModel, but it is unnoticed when there is more labels like this one.

Thanks
Jakub

**SOLUTION:**

Use Convertor:

```
public class StringMultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return string.Format(values.Last() as string, values);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In WPF add convertor to Resources:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <myComponents:StringMultiValueConverter x:Key="stringMultiValueConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

In Label add:

```
<Label.Content>
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource stringMultiValueConverter}">
                <Binding Path="Lib1" />
                <Binding Path="Lib2" />
                <Binding Path="LabelStringFormat" Source="{Dynamic Texts}"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
</Label.Content>
```

This work when string format is last param of Multibinding.

Comment: As evident from the error you can't use Binding for StringFormat because it's not a DP. Use `IValueConverter` instead to convert value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the "LabelStringFormat" as a parameter of the multi-binding:

```
<MultiBinding>
    <Binding Path="Lib1" />
    <Binding Path="Lib2" />
    <Binding Path="LabelStringFormat" Source="{DynamicResource Texts}" />
</MultiBinding>
```

Do the formatting from your IValueConverter using `String.Format((string)values[2], values[0], values[1])`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to use a Binding on the MultiBinding.StringFormat property. Instead, can you do something like this?

```
<Label.Content>
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{DynamicResource Texts.LabelStringFormat}">
                <Binding Path="Lib1" />
                <Binding Path="Lib2" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
</Label.Content>
```

Comment: When I try this, I got error:

A 'DynamicResourceExtension' cannot be set on the 'StringFormat' property of type 'MultiBinding'. A 'DynamicResourceExtension' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

When I use StaticResourceExtension:

Cannot set MultiBinding because MultiValueConverter must be specified.